# Rails data inside map with struct result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my class I build a daily liquidity state based on individual day records. It's a simple state function of previous dates, where:

- daily_state(day_1) = value(day_1)
- daily_state(day_N) = value(day_N) + daily_state(day_N-1)

Code below:

```
  def build
    days.each_with_index.map do |_, index|
      days[index][:total_sum] += days[index - 1][:total_sum] unless index.zero?
      build_single(days[index])
    end
  end


  def build_single(day)
    Liquidity::DailyRecord.new(day[:day], day[:total_sum])
  end
```

```
Liquidity::DailyRecord = Struct.new(
  :day,
  :total_sum
)
```

But now I want to extend this functionality by adding `revenues_sum` into the struct to be like:

```
Liquidity::DailyRecord = Struct.new(
  :day,
  :total_sum,
  :revenues_sum
)
```

How to change map from `build` method to handle below data:

```
days = [
  {:day=>Mon, 23 Nov 2020, :total_sum=>#<Money fractional:0 currency:EUR4>},
  {:day=>Tue, 24 Nov 2020, :total_sum=>#<Money fractional:0 currency:EUR4>},
  {:day=>Sun, 29 Nov 2020, :total_sum=>#<Money fractional:0 currency:EUR4>, :revenues_sum=>#<Money fractional:0 currency:EUR4>},
  {:day=>Mon, 30 Nov 2020, :total_sum=>#<Money fractional:39999786000 currency:EUR4>, :revenues_sum=>#<Money fractional:40000000000 currency:EUR4>},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you should be able to achieve this by slightly updating your code,

```rb
def build(days)
  days.each_with_index.map do |_, index|
    days[index][:total_sum] += days[index - 1][:total_sum] unless index.zero?
    days[index][:revenues_sum] = 0 if days[index][:revenues_sum].nil?
    days[index][:revenues_sum] += days[index - 1][:revenues_sum] unless index.zero?
    build_single(days[index])
  end
end

def build_single(day)
  Liquidity::DailyRecord.new(day[:day], day[:total_sum], day[:revenues_sum])
end
```